# Spring Cloud Gateway with Multiple Resource Servers

Tags: keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway instance with Eureka and KeyCloak as the Resource Server.

Gateway is configured as;

```
security:
  oauth:
    registration:
      gateway:
        provider: keycloak
        client-id: xxxx
        client-authentication-method: none
        scope: xxxx
    provider:
      keycloak:
        issuer-uri: xxx/realms/realmOne
```

The micro-service behind the Gateway's settings are;

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: xxx/realms/realmOne
```

This KeyCloak Client is linked to Windows Active Directory (Standard Flow = ON Direct Access Grant = ON, Implicit Flow = OFF). So any URL hit on this service would redirect to the KeyCloak login page, after which the credentials are confirms by AD. After which the JWT issues and URL access can continue.

**However** we now have background processes which need to access these URL. Obviously, the background process will not be able to login.

Therefore, I believe that I need a new KeyCloak Client with "Authorization" enabled (Implicit Flow = ON, Service Account = ON Authorization = ON).

So can the current Gateway deal with more than one KeyCloak Client. If yes, how? If not, would I need a second Gateway to use the same KeyCloak Realm but to the new Client?